# change imported font name

Tags: css, fonts

I am using a font from Google Fonts, so the import rule is like this:

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen';
```

However, I'd like to later change the name of the font to something else. Is there  a way that I can change it, maybe with a `font-face`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the url specified you'll find it's a set of @font-face rules. Just copy it; put it in a stylesheet of your own and change the names?? (Not sure about legality!)

Comment: yes, the legality is my concern. I would've done that, but I'm not sure about the terms that google provides.